# I can not see the symbol from loaded coredump using gdb

Tags: android, linux, debugging, gdb, coredump

all~

I can not see the symbol from loaded coredump using gdb.

I loaded the coredump file as below sequence.

```
$gdb
(gdb) core-file vold.corefile
[New LWP 3833]
[New LWP 3834]
[New LWP 3835]
Core was generated by `/system/bin/vold'.
Program terminated with signal 3, Quit.
#0  0xb6eaffc8 in ?? ()

(gdb) symbol-file ./out/target/product/msm8974/obj/EXECUTABLES/vold_intermediates/LINKED/vold
Reading symbols from /home/p14291/MSM8974_KK/SYS/EF63/MSM8974_KK/out/target/product/msm8974/obj/EXECUTABLES/vold_intermediates/LINKED/vold...done.

(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6eaffc8 in ?? ()
#1  0xb6ebd316 in ?? ()
#2  0xb6ebd316 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

As you see, I can not see the any symbol information.

How to see the symbol information on backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

> I can not see the any symbol information.

This most often happens when you load the wrong binary into GDB. You should

- Use the canonical way to invoke GDB:

  `gdb out/target/product/msm8974/obj/EXECUTABLES/vold vold.core`
- Confirm that your binary `out/target/product/msm8974/obj/EXECUTABLES/vold` is exactly the same as `/system/bin/vold` on the target system that generated the core dump (modulo stripping -- if one binary is a stripped version of another, that's ok).