How to analyze a coredump Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted
I am trying to analyze a coredump with gdb, but I am fairly new to this stuff and cannot pin down why this coredumped in the first place other than "Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted." which does not tell me why, how or what was the cause (like memory? cpu?). How can I read the below?
 [New LWP 28817]
 [New LWP 28812]
 [New LWP 28814]
 [New LWP 28816] 
 [New LWP 28813]
 [New LWP 28810]
 [New LWP 28815]

 **Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
 #0  0x00007f19e05ae2c7 in ?? ()**
 Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
 #0  0x00007f19e05ae2c7 in ?? ()
 "/data/coredumps/eea-amgr-xxxxxxxxxxxx-28810-6-1713991244" is a core file.
 Please specify an executable to debug.
(gdb) where
 #0  0x00007f19e05ae2c7 in ?? ()
 #1  0x00007f19e05af9b8 in ?? ()
 #2  0x0000000000000020 in ?? ()
 #3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0x00007f19e05ae2c7 in ?? ()
 #1  0x00007f19e05af9b8 in ?? ()
 #2  0x0000000000000020 in ?? ()
 #3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
 (gdb) thread
 [Current thread is 1 (LWP 28817)]

I tried bt, where and thread but I do not know how to translate the results.

You are probably loading coredump in a wrong way. Try gdb -c /data/coredumps/eea-amgr-xxxxxxxxxxxx-28810-6-1713991244.

Thanks but unfortunately gdb -c still gives the same information:
 Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
 #0  0x00007f19e05ae2c7 in ?? ()
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0x00007f19e05ae2c7 in ?? ()
 #1  0x00007f19e05af9b8 in ?? ()
 #2  0x0000000000000020 in ?? ()
 #3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
 (gdb) thread
 [Current thread is 1 (LWP 28817)]
 (gdb) where
 #0  0x00007f19e05ae2c7 in ?? ()
 #1  0x00007f19e05af9b8 in ?? ()
 #2  0x0000000000000020 in ?? ()
 #3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
 (gdb)


You also need to tell GDB about the executable that matches the core file.  Specifically, GDB is going to get the debug information from that executable.  This is why you get all the ?? in your backtrace -- GDB currently has no debug information.  From the (gdb) prompt you can do file /path/to/your/exec or start GDB as gdb -c /path/to/corefile /path/to/executable.  The executable needs to be the same one that produced the core file, and needs to have debug information.

Likely a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20998804/50617
